# Could not find a configuration file for package pr2_controller_interface

Tags: catkin-make, rosmake, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the pr2_mechanism tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20realtime%20joint%20controller)
it uses 'rosbuild' to build the code which is quite outdated. So in the part 3 of the tutorial, I use 'catkin_make' to build my package instead of using 'rosmake' which is used in the tutorial.  But I overcome two errors:

```
1. Could not find a configuration file for package pr2_mechanism_model.
2. Could not find a configuration file for package pr2_controller_interface.
```

I can 'roscd' these two packages so I think they should have been found by catkin_make. Can anyone tell me the solution? Thank you very much.

This is the 'find_package" in my CMakeList.txt:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  pluginlib
  pr2_controller_interface
  pr2_mechanism_model
)
```

PS. Can anyone update the tutorials to use the new build system catkin_make? And I find that some tutorials are quite outdated and need updating immediately. But since I am new to ROS and PR2, I cannot do more but asking questions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188624/could-not-find-a-configuration-file-for-package-pr2_controller_interface/) by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2014-08-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-05**:
Which version of ROS are you using? Are the pr2_mechanism_model and pr2_controller_interface packages that you're depending on catkin packages?

**Comment by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) on 2014-08-05**:
I am using groovy on Ubuntu Precise.  I can 'roscd' these two packages which means they are in my system.  And I also 'find_package()' both of them in CMakeList.txt. I think I should modify the CMakeList.txt to make it find the corresponding cmake file, right?

**Comment by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) on 2014-08-05**:
I have added the 'find_package' in my question. You can read it. @ahendrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The PR2 packages are not catkinized in Groovy. You'll have to use rosbuild.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) on 2014-08-05**:
Could you tell me how to catkinize it? Yes, I try and rosbuild works. Actually it comes to the question of why we should use catkin if rosbuild works to achieve the same goal.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-05**:
catkin packages cannot depend on rosbuild packages, and ALL of the PR2 packages in Groovy were rosbuild. You'd have to catkinze all of them. I did this. It was not fun. The catkinized versions of the PR2 packages are released into Hydro.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-05**:
The reasons for using catkin for released packages are many and varied. See: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/conceptual_overview

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-05**:
rosbuild is still supported and works well for a single developer or a small team building packages from source, but it doesn't scale well to released packages.